# XSL for XML to HTML conversion: color the xml data values based on positive or negative

Tags: html, xml, xslt

XSL for XML to HTML conversion: color the xml data values based on whether they are positive or negative

My XML file.

```
<roots>
    <root>
    <text1>increased by</text1>
    <value1>10</value1>
    <text2>decreased by<text2>
    <value2>-7</value2>
    </root>
</roots>
```

Expected HTML output:

```
increased by 10 --(value 10 in green color)
decreased by -7 -- (value -7 in red color)
```

and Iam trying to implement XSLT below way...

```
<xsl:template match="value1">
<xsl:if test="value1 >= 0">
     <font color="green"><xsl:apply-templates/>/></font>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value1">
<xsl:if test="value1 < 0">
     <font color="red"><xsl:apply-templates/>/></font>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This `<xsl:apply-templates/>/>` is not valid XML -- is this in your code or is it just a typo in your post?

Comment: Does your XML really contain numbered nodes: text1, text2, value1, value2, etc. ?

Comment: yes @ michael.hor257k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two templates with exactly the same match pattern - that's not going to work. Use either a distinct match pattern for each template e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="value1[. >= 0]">
```

and:

```
<xsl:template match="value1[. &lt; 0]">
```

or a single template with `xsl:choose` to select the color.

Note also that you have several syntax errors, for example `<xsl:apply-templates/>/>` (double closing of a tag) or the attempt to use an unescaped `<` character as a comparison operator.

---

### Added:

If, as you say, your XML really contain numbered nodes (text1, text2, value1, value2, etc.) then you must change your match pattern to account for that. Otherwise you would need as many templates as there are values in the input (twice as many, if you want separate templates for positive and negative values).

For example, using a single template for both cases, with `xsl:choose` to select the color:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'value')]">
    <xsl:variable name="color">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". >= 0">green</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>red</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <font color="{$color}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </font>     
    <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have one question, Can we able to produce Bar Graphs or Pie Charts in HTML output? and if need other technology except JavaScript I don't want to use any other. [XML, XSLT, JavaScript . with help of these 3 can i produce Graphs in HTML output ? ]